# Voltage and current of a capacitor while discharging

Tags: capacitor, capacitance

What will be the values of voltage and current across the load at t = 0+ instant as soon as it is connected across a fully charged capacitor ?

Is voltage and current at t = 0+ instant independent of load resistance ?

Comment: "0+ instant", I don't get it.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC_time_constant, read this.

Comment: What load? Homework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the instant a load is connected to a supply like a capacitor, the load voltage and the supply voltage become equal, regardless of the load. The current then evolves according to what the load is. If the load has some inductance, then the current rises slowly. If the load is pure resistance, and the supply is ideal, and everything is small, then the current rises instantly.

Don't get too hung up on the impossibility of the current rising instantly into a resistive load, it never does. The source and load will always have some inductance, and the circuit is never 'small', there will always be transmission line effects. If you model ideal components, then you will get ideal instant behaviour. If you model sources, connections and loads with inductance and physical length, then you'll see more realistic finite things happening.

Answer (score 0):

The load resistor when connected to fully charged capacitor at t = 0+ instant, the load voltage is independent of load resistance. It means the maximum voltage of a capacitor ( i.e., the peak voltage of capacitor when connected to supply ) will going to appear across the load. This is  reason why capacitor is called as voltage source at t = 0+ instant(i.e., as soon as you connect fully charged capacitor to load).

It means at t = 0+ instant voltage across the load is independent of load resistance.but the current drawn from the capacitor is dependent on load resistance. Therefore load current is dependent quantity and load voltage is independent quantity of load resistance at t = 0+ instant.